# go と database/sql で構造体がない場合でも値を取得したい。

Tags: sql, go, database

go と database/sql を使って以下のようなコードを書きました。
やりたい事としては、hoge テーブルからデータを select して、その内容を取得する事です。

DB のデータ構造は構造体におこさない条件があります。

`*val` には DB から取得した値が入る想定でしたが、数値の配列が入っています。
この数値は何を表しているのでしょうか？ また、正しくレコードの値を取得する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

```golang
rows, err := db.Query("select * from hoge")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
columns, err := rows.Columns()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

count := len(columnNames)
args := make([]interface{}, count)
pointers := make([]interface{}, count)

for i, _ := range args {
    pointers[i] = &args[i]
}

for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(pointers...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for i, n := range columnNames {
        val := pointers[i].(*interface{})
        log.Println(*val) // [50 48 50 48 45 48 51 45 48 54 32 49 50 58 53 56 58 52 55]
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `[50 48 50 ...]` は `2020-03-06 12:58:47` という文字列(string)を byte array([]byte) に変換したものです。

Comment: 文字列のまま取得する良い方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

データベーステーブルのカラム情報を、[sql.Rows.ColumnTypes()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.ColumnTypes) と [sql.ColumnType.ScanType()](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#ColumnType.ScanType) を利用して取得するサンプルプログラムを以下に示します。データベースは sqlite3 を使用しています。

`reflect.New()` で各カラムに対応する Go の型(type)のインスタンス(ポインタ)を作成して、それらを `sql.Rows.Scan()` に渡しています。ポインタですので、値を取り出すのに `reflect.Value.Elem()` を使います。

**sql_example.go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    // Connect to database
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./test.db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Select records
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * from hoge")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    // No records
    if !rows.Next() {
        return
    }

    // Column types
    ct, err := rows.ColumnTypes()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    types := make([]reflect.Type, len(ct))
    for i, typ := range ct {
        types[i] = typ.ScanType()
    }

    // Column values
    values := make([]interface{}, len(ct))
    for i := range values {
        values[i] = reflect.New(types[i]).Interface()
    }

    // Scan
    for {
        err := rows.Scan(values...)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        for _, v := range values {
            fmt.Printf("%v|", reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem())
        }
        fmt.Println()

        if !rows.Next() {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**実行結果**

```
$ sqlite3 test.db <<EOS
CREATE TABLE hoge (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime'))
);
INSERT INTO hoge VALUES (1, '2020-03-06 12:58:47');
INSERT INTO hoge VALUES (2, '2020-04-28 01:36:20');
INSERT INTO hoge VALUES (3, '2020-05-15 15:10:12');
EOS

$ sqlite3 test.db <<EOS
SELECT * from hoge;
EOS
1|2020-03-06 12:58:47
2|2020-04-28 01:36:20
3|2020-05-15 15:10:12

$ go run sql_example.go
1|2020-03-06T12:58:47Z|
2|2020-04-28T01:36:20Z|
3|2020-05-15T15:10:12Z|
```